# can't use WaitForSeconds with OnMouseDown

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I used `OnMouseDown()` to deactivate an object but i want the object to activate again in a few seconds. I have used `WaitForSeconds()` for other things but this time it just doesn't work

this is what i could gather by researching (the deactivating part works fine):

```
void Start()
{
    StartCoroutine(wait());
}

void Update(){}

void OnMouseDown()
{
    gameObject.SetActive(false);
}

IEnumarator wait()
{
    yield return new WaitForSeconds(3);
    gameObject.SetActive(true);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are **too many** reasons your code isn't work right. You are doing it backwards. Your **coroutine** **starts** **immediately** when your program starts because `wait()` is called from the Start() function.  When it starts, it pauses for 3 seconds and set your GameObject to `SetActive(true)`;

If your GameObject is already visible to the screen, your code wont do anything because `SetActive(true)` will be called even when it is visible.  If you fail to press/click on the screen before that 3 seconds, you wont be able to see `SetActive(true)`; because your coroutine code would have finished running by that time.

Also, if you **disable** a GameObject, the coroutine attached to it will **stop**. The solution is to create a **reference** of the **GameObject** you want to **disable** then use that **reference** to **disable** and **enable** it from **another** **script** without problems.

Since provided a code, I fixed/re-wrote it for you. I replaced the OnMouseDown  fucntion with something more robust.

All you have to do is **create** an empty GameObject. **Attach** this **script** to that **empty GameObject**. Then **drag** and **drop** that **GameObject** you want to **disable** and **enable** to the this "**Game Object To Disable**" ***slot*** in this **script**, from the **Editor**.

Do **NOT** attach this script to that **GameObject** you want to **disable** and **enable**.

*Tested with cube and it worked.*

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class ALITEST: MonoBehaviour
{
    //Reference to the GameObject you want to Disable/Enable
    //Drag the Object you want to disable here(From the Editor)
    public GameObject gameObjectToDisable;

    void Start()
    {

    }

    void Update()
    {
        //Keep checking if mouse is pressed
        checkMouseClick();
    }

    //Code that checks when the mouse is pressed down(Replaces OnMouseDown function)
    void checkMouseClick()
    {
        //Check if mouse button is pressed
        if (Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0))
        {
            RaycastHit hitInfo = new RaycastHit();
            if (Physics.Raycast(Camera.main.ScreenPointToRay(Input.mousePosition), out hitInfo))
            {
                //Check if the object clicked is that object
                if (hitInfo.collider.gameObject == gameObjectToDisable)
                {
                    Debug.Log("Cube hit");
                    StartCoroutine(wait()); //Call the function to Enable/Disable stuff
                }
            }
        }
    }

    //This value is used to make sure that the coroutine is not called again while is it already running(fixes many bugs too)
    private bool isRunning = false;

    IEnumerator wait(float secondsToWait = 3)
    {
        //Exit coroutine while it is already running
        if (isRunning)
        {
            yield break; //Exit
        }
        isRunning = true;

        //Exit coroutine if gameObjectToDisable is not assigned/null
        if (gameObjectToDisable == null)
        {
            Debug.Log("GAME OBJECT NOT ATTACHED");
            isRunning = false;
            yield break; //Exit
        }
        gameObjectToDisable.SetActive(false);

        //Wait for x amount of Seconds
        yield return new WaitForSeconds(secondsToWait);

        //Exit coroutine if gameObjectToDisable is not assigned/null
        if (gameObjectToDisable == null)
        {
            Debug.Log("GAME OBJECT NOT ATTACHED");
            isRunning = false;
            yield break; //Exit
        }
        gameObjectToDisable.SetActive(true);
        isRunning = false;
    }
}
```

Comment: I can't thank you enough. this answer actually solved a few other of my problems as well

Comment: an extremely generous answer

Answer (score 0):

Because you're calling `StartCoroutine()` in `Start()`, your coroutine will resume 3 seconds after the component is started. You want to call `StartCoroutine(wait())` in `OnMouseDown()` so the GameObject will become active after that.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot deactivate `GameObject` and continue `Coroutine` on it. If you deactivate `GameObject` that has runing `Coroutine` it will be stoped.

So if you want to do it right, you need `Coroutine` runing on other `GameObject` and from there actvating this `GameObject`.

If you need more help, ask.